# HttpURLConnection getoutputstream() thread sate is going to BLOCKED

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, httpurlconnection

I'm using the HttpURLConnection class to make http requests. My code looks something like this :

```
conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(endPoint.trim()).openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(rtbTimeOut); // 200 ms
    conn.setReadTimeout(rtbTimeOut);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod(ApiConstants.REQUEST_POST_METHOD); 
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",ApiConstants.CONTENT_TYPE);      
    conn.setRequestProperty("x-openrtb-version", ApiConstants.RTB_REQUEST_HEADER);  
    os = conn.getOutputStream(); // **Here is code of line that my Thread state is BLOCKED**
    os.write(input.getBytes());
    os.flush();
```

When I have debugged this issue on production environment I found the 
error in thread dump 
error : **"pool-424-thread-7" #4082 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8510144800 nid=0x5828 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f848b7f5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor**
on above code method getOutputStream() line

I am not getting why its going to BLOCKING state or any other implementation to avoid this state

Your help would be really appreciated . Thank You :)

Comment: just a small question for clarification : how do you expect your current attempt to be *"parallely"*? Because in the above snippet it isnt. At all. Zero parallelisation.

Comment: I have written ExecutorService thread pool for achieve hit parallel request to    different URL's so I couldn't add that code snippet because problem is in  this above code snippet. @specializt